How to turn off Passkey functionality in Google Chrome?
In my opinion it's not so much Android question despite I have an Android phone related to the problem but rather Google Chrome browser settings issue but my question initially posted in Superuser got downvoted and then closed right after and I was told to ask it here by the moderator...
Problem: I'm unable to authenticate to AWS web console in Google Chrome browser due to browser forcibly asking me a Passkey which I don't have. I can't also set it up due to owning a not compatible Android phone. I literally am switching browser just to login to AWS atm.
Rarely but persistently in every few months I have a situation where Google Chrome starts asking for Passkey when I try to log into my AWS Console in browser. Meanwhile when I'm asked for passkey then there is no place in AWS login-view to use password instead. AWS at the moment has the "old login" and "new login" views possible and both act the same- I am asked for passkey without possibility to use password instead. After clicking "Cancel", I'm just displayed with "Troubleshoot MFA" link which forwards me to AWS documentation and it does not help me or possibility to "Cancel" the authentication, which forwards me back to the AWS Console login form again.
What I've tried:

I read the AWS documentation given in the link above- no help
I have tried the setting described in this Google forum post but this didn't change my situation at all, even after restarting the browser.
In my phone settings I checked "Devices & sharing" -> "Passkey linked devices" and it was empty. Just to be sure I "Cleared" the device list still. No change in AWS login after that though- still demanding the Passkey.

Changing my phone isn't an option to start forcibly using passkeys. I have 2FA setup anyway through my external device.
How to turn off this aggressive Passkey requirement from Google for AWS (or any other service's authentication)?

Yesterday this issue disappeared for ONE DAY. Today it's back again while I didn't change anything :/
